# Where does ${authAdminUrl} come from and how do I manipulate it?

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to setup a (dockerized) keycloak instance but, after successful login, its' Security-admin-console keeps redirecting me to an internal URL instead of the URL I have setup in dns. Looking into the settings, its Root URL is set to `${authAdminUrl}`. I could override this value with an actual URL but I'd much rather change the value of the variable. So where does ${authAdminUrl} come from, and more importantly, how do I manipulate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the whole admin base URL (including scheme and port) can be configured in the *standalone.xml* file,
section `<spi name="hostname">`.
There you can add a property "**adminUrl**".
It's briefly mentioned in the [Installation Guide, Hostname/Default provider](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#default-provider).

Example:

```
<spi name="hostname">
  <default-provider>default</default-provider>
  <provider name="default" enabled="true">
    <properties>
        <property name="frontendUrl" value="${keycloak.frontendUrl:}"/>
        <property name="forceBackendUrlToFrontendUrl" value="false"/>
        <property name="adminUrl" value="https://myhost:10443/auth"/>
    </properties>
  </provider>
</spi>
```

Comment: +1 This is probably a better solution than the one I found. Unfortunately it does come with the requirement that you build your own docker image to contain the changes to the `standalone.xml` file, which in turn more or less requires your own docker image hosting solution etc. That was not something available to us at the time.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: environment variable `KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME`

A little more nuanced:

The value for the placeholder `${authAdminUrl}` is a complete URL, whereas the environment variable `KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME` is only the hostname; so without protocol, port number, or path. In my case, this doesn't matter because I'm not doing anything special with these so the default url formed with the custom hostname is good for me.