# Where does ${authAdminUrl} come from?

Tags: keycloak

for the default clients (i.e. admin) the *Base URL* is set to `/realms/something/account/`. The *Root URL* is set to `${authBaseUrl}`.

When I look in the clients overview, I can see the *Base URL* is shown as `https://mydomain/auth/realms/something/account/`

I'm trying to understand where the values `mydomain` and `auth` come from.

I´ve read [Where does ${authAdminUrl} come from and how do I manipulate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62534034/where-does-authadminurl-come-from-and-how-do-i-manipulate-it) and can confirm that the variable is not set in `standalone.xml` and also not set via environment variable `KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME`.

Answer (score 1):

This page: https://www.keycloak.org/server/hostname#_administration_console doesn't mention `authAdminUrl` explicitly, but the value specified in `--hostname-admin-url` as suggested there got picked in admin clients that use `authAdminUrl` in my environment.